# Convert Virtualbox VM to Amazon AMI

Tags: virtualbox, amazon-ami, packer

I've used [www.packer.io](http://www.packer.io/) to make a vagrant VirtualBox VM for Windows using the vagrant-windows plugin, now I want to pkg
it up and run it on ec2. Is it possible to use the virtual box hard drive verbatim for the generated AMI? I ask this because the programs I have installed are rather large and I'd like to keep them installed the way they are on the VM.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you need to do is add a new builder to your template.

https://www.packer.io/intro/getting-started/parallel-builds.html

By adding a new builder for AMI packer will build both vms with the same provisioners. Both vms should look similar in the end.

I do not think packer will convert the virtualbox disk to AMI. It will use the same provisioners to build both vms.